# Is there a way to transfer filter values between different analytics dashboards that are on different lightning tabs?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, einstein-analytics, filters, einstein-analytics-dashboards

We currently have different analytics dashboards embedded in aura tabset components. There are also different lightning tabs with the same aura tabset component layout/function that also have multiple tabs of dashboards.

The requirement is for users to be able to select values in one or more filters on one dashboard and, if the next dashboard has those same filters of course, have those values transfer/persist to the next dashboard they navigate to. This could be a different dashboard within the same tabset component or maybe a different lightning tab all together.

I've read documentation on the wave:update and wave:selectionChanged aura events but I'm afraid I'm not understanding the technical aspect all too well. I also haven't be able to find any examples of this being done.

Comment: Check if this helps you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--_167HG0n8&t=1094s